# How to get the "average" of a time series LSTM keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence

So just an FYI, I have a pretty limited understanding of the mechanics of machine learning, LSTM, and time series modeling, but based on my current understanding, I feel like since I have a LSTM time series model trained on many time series plots, I should be able to get its "average" time series based on all of the ones it's trained on.

What's the best way to accomplish that?

I have a keras Sequential model, and I don't know if any code would even be helpful in this instance, but if there is any code that would assist, let me know!

EDIT: Here is some of the data

```
32.1576
31.92
31.7
31.85
32.05
32.5
32.3
31.975
31.7
32.15
32.6
32.55
32.4
32.4835
32.25
32.15
32.25
32.45
32.4
32.5002
32.45
32.5
32.5752
33.1748
33
33.35
33.45
33.45
33.425
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of your data? It is not clear what average time series means from an LSTM.

Comment: @nuric I put a sample of the data in the main post. It's just one column of data. The time series is just a plot of that data. But I train my model off of normalized data from many different sources, but they're all in the same kind of general format as the data given above.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to have the input of your LSTM be several time series, and then the output be a time series that is 'average' given the sampels? Why not just take the literal average of all the time series? What exactly do you want?

Comment: @modesitt the output is predictions of the next three values given all of the earlier inputs. I'm looking for I guess the average overall plot for a given range. If I just ask it to predict all of the values, it seems to just flatten out to some kind of equilibrium.

Answer (score 0):

You can use keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D in order to average the time series. If the input shape is `(batch_size, steps, features)`, the output shape is `(batch_size, features)`. Weather or not you are using a Sequential model doesn't matter in this case. This layer works juts like any other layer in Keras. More information here: https://keras.io/layers/pooling/#globalaveragepooling1d